# How can I split text (within an XML element) on multiple lines without having line break or unwated spaces in the resulting view?

Tags: xml, formatting, pretty-print

I have a code similar to this:

```
<container>
    <source>
        <name>Title</name>
        <text>Some very long text that i need to split in two lines for pretty print purpose and readability.</text>
    </source>
</container>
```

---

Is is possible to have the second line of the *text* element to start at the same point (row) as the line above it, for pretty print, whithou resulting in unwanted spaces in the final view? Something like this:

```
    <source>
        <name>Title</name>
        <text>Some very long test that i need to split in two lines for pretty print 
        purpose and readability.</text>
    </source>
</container>
```

How can I make something like that work?

---

I'm working with Notepad++.
If you need any other information, ask me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces that occur in the following positions in an XML document are called 'mixed content' and are not (usually) considered meaninful:

- before the opening of the first child tag
- between the close of one tag and the start of its next sibling tag
- after the close of the end tag

When XML is pretty printed, it is normally done by adding mixed content in these positions to indent the tags and show the hierarchy.

However, text that occurs between the open tag and the close tag is 'element content' and *is* meaningful. If you insert line breaks and spaces into the element value of the  tag then you are changing the document. If you want to remove that whitespace before displaying the text value then you will need to add custom code into your UI/XML viewer.

Alternatively (if the XSD is under your control) you could allow the  tag to repeat. That would allow you to keep the XML nice and pretty while allowing more text. Again, you would need to write code to concatenate the values of all  tags before presenting the value to the UI/viewer.